# Engineers Australia work experience assessment

Tags: working-visas, australia

I have been assessed by EA for my work experience. EA has given me 2 years of positive assessment even though I have 4 years of work experience, by saying that my first two years of work experience was on student visa. I'm an expatriate in Qatar.

My question is that can I still go ahead and apply to DIBP claiming points for 4 years as I have heard DIBP assesses the work experience independently. I have reference letters and pay slips from the company but I do not have bank statement as I was paid in cash.